# How to get file name in encoded form of the file which is inside zip file

Tags: java, android

File name inside a zip file is encoded with some random encoding algorithm and if i try to extract with native Zipfile of ZIP4J Zipfile it is trying to decode with UTF-8.

Is there any way to know the encoding algorithm of the file name which is inside .zip file before extraction?

Comment: Interesting; which part of the ZIP header tells about file name encoding? And why doesn't UTF-8 work for you?

Comment: Because file name was encoded with some other encoding algorithm so

Comment: That does not answer my question...

Comment: Not sure how to get the encoding algorithm from zip file